FPS Control for OV7670
Can anyone clarify if cameras like the OV5642 or OV7670 have a relationship between FPS and the XCLK frequency supplied to the camera from an external oscillator? Specifically, can I achieve FPS lower than the maximum for a given resolution by reducing the input XCLK? For instance, instead of 30 FPS for 720p, could I get 25 FPS by lowering the XCLK? Or is there another way to accomplish this?
Regarding the OV7670, its input XCLK frequency ranges from 10 to 48 MHz, but the timing parameters in the documentation are given in units of "tp",as shown in the picture. As I understand, "tp" refers to the period of the pixel clock (PCLK) at the camera's output. However, I am unsure how this period is calculated, especially if PCLK is not fixed.

The registers mention dividers for PCLK, and one could assume that these dividers define PCLK and, consequently, the FPS by dividing the input XCLK. However, I wanted to clarify this with more knowledgeable individuals. The Omnivision documentation is quite confusing to me.

I haven't programmed these Omnivision cameras myself, but looking at the Linux Kernel ov7670.c driver source file there is the following comment in the ov7675_set_framerate function about how the frame rate (fps) is calculated:
    /*
     * The formula is fps = 5/4*pixclk for YUV/RGB and
     * fps = 5/2*pixclk for RAW.
     *
     * pixclk = clock_speed / (clkrc + 1) * PLLfactor
     *
     */

Other comments in the driver suggest the developer had to reverse-engineer some details, such as the following also in the ov7675_set_framerate function:
    /*
     * The datasheet claims that clkrc = 0 will divide the input clock by 1
     * but we've checked with an oscilloscope that it divides by 2 instead.
     * So, if clkrc = 0 just bypass the divider.
     */

This answer doesn't directly address the points in the question, but rather is a suggestion to study what an existing open-source driver does to set the FPS instead of having to rely upon the Omnivision documentation.
